# How to update treeview items made from itemtemplate on sizechanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

How do I update the treeview items made from an itemtemplate on a sizechanged event of the containing control?

I thought I would just get the container from the itemcontainergenerator and search for the control in the headertemplate. However, I get an error because the header template is not applied.

```
 private void SignalBox_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.WidthChanged)
      {
        double change_in_width = e.NewSize.Width - e.PreviousSize.Width;
        signal_graph_window_width = ActualWidth - NamePanelWidth;
        TreeView tv = this.signal_treeview_item_control;
        foreach (var item in tv.Items)
        {
          TreeViewItem container = tv.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as TreeViewItem;
          if (container != null && container.HeaderTemplate.Is)
          {
            SignalGraph sg = container.HeaderTemplate.FindName("signal_graph", container) as SignalGraph;
```

I read some more on the topic and it seems that the error i am getting is because the template has not yet been applied. Most of the answers I was reading about suggested binding an event handler to the onapplytemplate, but I can't react to just the onapplytemplate event or the size might not have changed.

I want my signalgraph to be able to draw based on the available size, and to redraw and update when the window's size changes.

edit: One poster suggests that I am going about this all wrong. Probably true, but I don't know how else to go about it.

I have a custom user control "signal_box" and I have a property "signal_graph_window_width" that is bound to signal_box's child FrameworkElement signalgraph.

signalgraph takes two properties to draw a graph, the signal_graph_window_width and the width of the signalgraph.  The former is how much actual space the window has and is calculated from window.actualwidth - signalnamepanel.width.  The latter is what determines how much data needs to actually be drawn.

signalgraph is wrapped in a grid that is wrapped in a scrollviewer, so that if there is more data than can show on the screen, you can scroll to see the rest. I wanted to put the scrollviewer only on the grid portion containing the signalgraph, so that the signalnames stay visible when you scroll.

Originally I had signalbox manually modify signalgraph on resize. This was done in the codebehind, updating the width of the signalgraph by finding the control with the right name in the itemtemplate of the ItemsControl.

This was all working fine when I had an itemcollection, but then I decided to use treeview so I could expand the actual signals.  Unfortunately, the codebehind modifications that grabbed the templated itemcontrol no longer worked with the new treeview templates.

Now in my mind the solution is to just figure out how to get access to the correct controls defined here:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource ="{Binding Path = bits}">
      <Grid x:Name="signal_box_grid" Background="Black">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <wpfExp:SignalNamePanel Grid.Column="0"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=GraphHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
            x:Name="signal_name_panel"
            MainText="{Binding Path = SignalName}" 
          />
        <wpfExp:SignalGraph Grid.Column="1"
            x:Name="signal_graph"
            IsSignal="True"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=GraphHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
            PenWidth="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=GraphPenWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
            Signal="{Binding}" 
            signal_graph_window_width="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=signal_graph_window_width, Mode=OneWay}"
            X_Scale="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=X_Scale, Mode=OneWay}"
            MaxTimeValue="{Binding RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type wpfExp:SignalBox}}, Path = _SignalData.MaxTimeValue}"
          />
      </Grid>


      <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <Grid Background="Black">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <wpfExp:SignalNamePanel Grid.Column="0"
                Height="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=GraphHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
                x:Name="signal_name_panel"
                MainText="{Binding Path = BitNumber}" 
              />
                <wpfExp:SignalGraph Grid.Column="1"
                x:Name="signal_graph"
                IsSignal="False"
                Height="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=GraphHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
                PenWidth="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=GraphPenWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
                Bit="{Binding}" 
                signal_graph_window_width="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=signal_graph_window_width, Mode=OneWay}"
                X_Scale="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=X_Scale, Mode=OneWay}"
                MaxTimeValue="{Binding RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type wpfExp:SignalBox}}, Path = _SignalData.MaxTimeValue}"
              />
              </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
          </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

but perhaps I am just going about it all wrong.

The reason that I want to modify the width of the graph based on Sizechanged is because when the user resizes the window beyond the drawn length of the signal, i want to redraw the signal and extend it to the end of the window.

As can be seen here, when I resize, the signal is not being redrawn to the end of the screen. How should I let signalgraph know that it needs to draw more to reach the end of the screen?

http://picpaste.com/signalgraph2-oObkPXLX.JPG

I have a viewmodel

```
   public class SignalDataViewModel
  {
    ObservableCollection<SignalViewModel> _signals;
    public ObservableCollection<SignalViewModel> Signals
    {
      get
      {
        return _signals;
      }
      private set
      {
        _signals = value;
      }
    }

    SignalData signal_data;
```

that takes signaldata and signaldata contains an observable collection of signals:

```
 public ObservableCollection<Signal> list_of_signals
    {
      get;
      set;
    }
```

which looks like this:

```
public class Signal
  {
    public bool isBus
    {
      get;
      private set;
    }
    public List<KeyValuePair<int, IList<byte>>> SignalValues
    {
      get;
      private set;
    }
    public List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> HexSignalValues
    {
      get;
      private set;
    }
    public string SignalName
    {
      get;
      private set;
    }
    public Signal(string name, bool isBus)
    {
      SignalValues = new List<KeyValuePair<int, IList<byte>>>();
      this.SignalName = name;
      this.isBus = isBus;
    }
```

I keep wondering whether i am not better off just using the itemscontrol method I had before and just manually creating the expand buttons. I figured learning to use the library is the correct method, but ultimately I think my real problem is, why doesn't scrollviewer update the size of the inner control. Is the proper solution to make a custom scrollbar that updates its content when it resizes?

Comment: `So I'm wondering how I should go about coding this` - You should NOT be manipulating UI elements' sizes in code to begin with. What is your real problem? WPF is resolution independent, and depending on the values of several properties (such as `VerticalAlignment` `HorizontalAlignment` and `Height` and `Width`), your container objects will enlarge/shrink when needed to properly layout their contents.

Comment: Could you explain then how I would change the width of a child control in xaml based on the resize of the parent?  Is the correct thing to do to use some sort of ICommand to tell the child control to resize? I can't just bind width, because I need to calculate a new width based on the size of the window and on the amount of data

Comment: `because I need to calculate a new width based on the size of the window and on the amount of data` - No you don't. You're thinking too winforms. Post a screenshot of what you need, and I can give you some sample XAML.

Comment: k, i revised the first post, but I bet you still need more information. Let me know what you need. I guess I'm just confused as to how to get scrollviewer to work with the signalgraphs so that both resize, zoomin and zoom out work as planned. ZoomOut I want to increase the length of the signals and zoomout i want to decrease them but still have them draw till the end of the screen. I had it all working, but I'm guessing I'm not doing things the right way since it seems very difficult to access templates in codebehind

Comment: Can you post the Data Item? I mean the class that represents the data you're graphing (the Model)

Comment: ok, actually maybe I just need to override measure and arrange properly on the child element. I assume these get re-called on sizechanged. Going to try that for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured out how to avoid manually calling the controls in the children and boy does the code look cleaner. Basically the problem was that I needed to both override MeasureOverride for my frameworkelement as well as change my bound properties to have the affectsmeasure metadata option.

```
public double signal_graph_window_width
    {
      get { return (double)GetValue(signal_graph_window_width_property); }
      set
      {
        SetValue(signal_graph_window_width_property, value);
      }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty signal_graph_window_width_property =
      DependencyProperty.Register("signal_graph_window_width",
      typeof(double), typeof(SignalGraph),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new double(), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));
```

By overriding measure properly, the frameworkelement's size gets updated, so then I can just an attach an event handler to sizechanged on the frameworkelement to force a redraw.